# Saving and Getting Level Number

Tags: android

I'm developing a level-based app, and I want to be able to save the user's level number (1, 2, 3 etc..) and then when the app starts get the level number and do something with it.
How can I do it?

Comment: Start here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: Have the answers helped you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [<kbd>Shared Preferences</kbd>](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) like so:

Create these methods for use, or just use the content inside of the methods whenever you want:

```
public int getLevel()
{
   SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("prefName", 0);
   int level = sp.getInt("levelReference", 1);
   return level;
}

public void setLevel(String level)
{
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("prefName", 0).edit();
   editor.putInt("levelReference", level);
   editor.commit();
}
```

The `1` in `sp.getInt("levelReference", 1);` means that the method will return `1` if the preference is not found, so the default level is 1.

You can call them like this:

```
int level = getLevel(); // level is now the level that the user is on

setLevel(4); // user is now on level 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SharedPreferences for storing level number:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

http://android-er.blogspot.ru/2011/01/example-of-using-sharedpreferencesedito.html

Answer (score 0):

If you read up in the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) you can see that to save data like a level number, you can use SharedPreferences. First, you'll need a SharedPreferences object, which you can obtain using

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Then to save a piece of data, use:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt("level", level);
editor.commit();
```

And finally, to get that level back later, use:

```
sharedPref.getInt("level", 0);
```

Good luck!